# Big maps in Zeronet

Tags: bigmap, zeronet

Is it true that in zeronet big maps are treated like regular maps?
Example:
https://rpc.tzkt.io/zeronet/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1JPvBo4Sv7n1WDzcKWEXTVRDU9HQhaZdzd
See no big map pointers in the storage but a list of `Elt`s instead, `big_map_diff` field is also empty in operations:
https://rpc.tzkt.io/zeronet/chains/main/blocks/493088/operations/3

Counterexample:
https://rpc.tzkt.io/zeronet/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/KT1EMy5cDrUQgNYZgtN4wX2n39MBqHGQQCiK
Origination: https://rpc.tzkt.io/zeronet/chains/main/blocks/335248/operations/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK a restriction in Athens is that a bigmap must be first element in the storage definition. Thats why KT1JPvBo4Sv7n1WDzcKWEXTVRDU9HQhaZdzd does not have a bigmap but KT1EMy5cDrUQgNYZgtN4wX2n39MBqHGQQCiK does. If you use type big_map somewhere else it gets translated into a regular map.